# About method override

Tags: java, overriding

For the following segment of java code, the method of “run” occurs four times. I am quite confusing about the relationships of these four occurrences of “run”. The original code is pretty long, I just keep the part that is related to my question.

```
   1. public final class Job extends AbstractJob {  
   2.   private Job( ) {  
   3.   }  
   4.   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
   5.            new Job( ).run(new Path("testdata"), output, 10 );  
   6.   }  
   7.   
   8.   @Override  
   9.   public int run(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,      InterruptedException {  
  10.         run(input, output, alpha0);  
  11.         return 0;  
  12.   }    
  13.   public void run(Path input,  Path output,  double alpha0)  
  14.     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {      
  15.     ClusterDriver.run(directoryInput, output, alpha0);      
  16.   }  
  17. }
```

Can I understnd the invoking sequence of this segment of code as follows.

At first, he run method at line 5 is called. Due to its particular parameter setting, 3 parameters, the compiler automatically uses the run method defined in line 13. ( if we only have one parameter in line 5, then compiler will use the run method defined in line 9 instead.

For the run method defined in line 9, it will call run method at line 10, which essentially is the run method defined at line 13.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: this is about method *overloading*, not *overriding*. And yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: You don't appear to be confused, sounds right to me.  Perhaps you lack confidence. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic analysis is correct.

(just to clarify the point that others have made: **overloading** is when methods have the same name but different signatures, whereas **overriding** is when a method has the same name and argument types as a method in a superclass)

For future reference, you should be aware that method resolution (name + arguments -> method selection) in Java, in the case of overloaded methods, can actually be quite difficult to understand. The exact behavior used is written up in the [Java Language Spec (JLS), section 15.12](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12), and involves a few general subtleties:

- Overloaded method resolution is done at *compile time*, not at runtime. (selection among method *overrides* with the *same signature* is done at runtime, based on the most specific subclass's method.) If the compiler knows an argument is an instance of `Foo` (e.g. its class is `Foo` or a subclass of `Foo`) then it will use `Foo` as the argument's class, not its "real" class.
- Issues that determine which method is used include:

  - whether a method is varargs or not (has `...` as the last argument e.g. `foo(Object a, String... b)`)
  - whether a method's declared arguments are primitives or wrapped primitives e.g. `float` vs `Float`
  - whether one method's declared arguments are "more specific" than another (subclasses are more specific than their superclasses)

This is complex but you have the basic understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct, except that this is method *overloading*, not overriding.

There are two `run` methods defined in this class, on lines 9 and 13, with different number of parameters. Hence the method `run` is *overloaded*. (*Overriding* happens if a virtual base class method is redefined in the subclass - it apparently happens with the method defined on line 9, as testified by its annotation, but this plays no role in this particular question.)

And there are two calls to `run` (on lines 5 and 10), which both resolve to calling the method with 3 parameters (defined on line 13).

Answer (score 0):

Only the last **run** method definition matters.

The other **run** method (which takes `String[]`) invokes this method, so it acts like some sort of "proxy", while the other `run` invocation in the `main` method can choose to invoke either of the two -- either the 'proxy' **run** method (which takes `String[] args`) or the last **run** method, which actually does the "running".

Answer (score 0):

You've got most of things right but few statements I want to correct are:

```
if we only have one parameter in line 5, then compiler will use the run method defined in line 9 instead.
```

That is not totally correct, the method on line 9 accepts `String[]` type arguments and you will need to pass an array to call this method.

```
For the run method defined in line 9, it will call run method at line 10, which essentially is the run method defined at line 13.
```

On line 10 you will get syntax error since `input, output, alpha0` are undefined in that method. You need to take passed `String[] args` argument and covert it into `input, output, alpha0` arguments to be call other implementation of `run`.